# unable to build a jekyll site ... invalid date

Tags: jekyll

when trying to build a jekyll site with "jekyll serve" I get this error:

```
  Generating...
         ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                ------------------------------------
                Invalid date '<%= Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z') %>': Document 'vendor/cache/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb' does not have a valid date in the YAML front matter.
```

ruby and jekyll were installed using homebrew on Mac OSX

Comment: What have you tried? What's in `vendor/cache/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb`?

Comment: It contains the following code:  ---
layout: post
title:  "Welcome to Jekyll!"
date:   <%= Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z') %>
categories: jekyll update
---
.... and more lines ...

Answer (score 35):

I found the answer ....

It seems that you need to place the line `exclude: [vendor]` in _config.yml

found this on the following Github issue:
https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2938

Comment: Exactly the same error as OP, but this solution didn't do anything :(

Comment: What worked for me is to delete `jekyll` folder inside `node_modules`, at leasts works for now :P

Comment: For me, `exclude: vendor` worked (without brackets).

Comment: This is for Jekyll <4 i believe, should be fixed in 4.0